# In text citing of Author (Date)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

How would I change my cite style for one specific citation?

throughout my document i am citing like this:

`An orthotropic material has mechanical properties that are unique along three mutually perpendicular axes \cite{green1999mechanical}`

which produces:

An orthotropic material has mechanical properties that are unique
along three mutually perpendicular axes (Green 1999)

Which is how I would like most of my citations to be done. However, sometimes I would like to refer to the author as follows:

Green (1999) states that an orthotropic material has mechanical properties that are unique
along three mutually perpendicular axes.

How would i do this?

Here is the code for text:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage [english]{babel}

\begin{document}

An orthotropic material has mechanical properties that are unique along three mutually perpendicular axes \cite{green1999mechanical}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{mastersref}

\end{document}
```

and my `.bib` file called mastersref.bib has the entry:

```
  author  = {David Green},
  journal = {Wood handbook/David W. Green, Jerrold E. Winandy, David E. Kretschmann.--Madison, WI: US Department of Agrieculture, Fofest Service, Products Laboratory},
  title   = {Mechanical Properties of Wood/David W. Green, Jerrold E. Winandy, David E. Kretschmann},
  year    = {1999},
  pages   = {4--1},
}
```

I am using bibtex and not biblatex
I have tried `\citet{}` and `\citeauthor{}` and `\citeonline{}`

Is this possible without using `natbib`

Comment: What’s the problem with using `natbib`?

Comment: no real problem, its just that for some reason using the `natbib` package all my `\cite{}` show as Author (Date) as well as my `\citet{}`. So im not getting any (Author, Date)

Comment: For that use `\citep`

Comment: Aggghh!!! so its just me not knowing how to use the package properly. This worked, thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: The fact that both the `journal` and the `title` field contain more than just the journal name and article title, respectively, but also author/editor names and location data suggest that the entry may be using the wrong entry type (the entry type seems to have been cut in a copy-and-paste mess-up, but I'm guessing it's `@article`). In case we are talking about https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/fplgtr/fpl_gtr190.pdf `@incollection` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main citation commands for `natbib` are the following:

- `\citet` : Author (Year)
- `\citep` : (Author, Year)
- `\cite` : Author (Year) in author year mode, and a numeric cite in numeric mode (this is not really recommended for use because of its split behaviour.)

Each citation command can optionally have a post-note in `[...]` as an optional argument.

There are also starred versions, which print out the full list of authors instead of using *et al.*.

You can also use `\citeyear` and `\citeauthor` to yield the year and author(s) respectively.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that `natbib` discourages use of `\cite`, because of its inconsistent behaviour between cite modes (which makes switching modes harder): "The standard LaTeX command `\cite` should be avoided, because it behaves like `\citet` for author–year citations, but like `\citep` for numerical ones." (p. 1 of the `natbib` documentation). This goes as far as not defining a `\Cite` command for capitalised author names (there are only `\Citet`, `\Citep`, `\Citealt`, `\Citealp`, `\Citeauthor`).

Comment: @moewe Thansk, I've added a comment about that.

Comment: Thank you very much.